Pressure Level dB coefficient 10, 20
I’m new to DSP, and I often work with microphone data, analyzing sound pressure levels in decibels (dB). However, I’m a bit confused about the equation for calculating dB. I’ve seen it expressed as both 20log(P/P₀) and 10log(P/P₀) in different places, and I’m not sure which one is correct. Shouldn’t there be a single standard for comparison? Could you explain this to me?
Thank you!

If analyzing sound pressure specifically, in dB it will be
$$L = 20\log_{10}(p/p_o)$$
where $p$ is a sound pressure measurement, and $p_o$ represents a reference pressure level (such as 0.00002 pascals as the threshold of hearing).
(Here I used the lower case $p$ to represent the pressure as an amplitude and below I will use capital $P$ to represent a power level.)
dB by definition is the log of a a ratio of powers multiplied by 10 (hence deci), given as:
$$dB = 10\log_{10}(P/P_o)$$
Where $P$ is a power measurement and $P_o$ is a reference power we are comparing it to.
Sound pressure is considered a magnitude quantity rather than a power quantity and can be given as an rms measurement, representing the amplitude of a sound wave typically measured in Pascals (Pa). If we have a ratio of magnitude quantities as ($p/p_o$), then we can get the ratio of power quantities by squaring those: $P/P_o = (p/p_o)^2$
From the property of logs that $\log(x^y) = y\log(x)$ we can get the two common expressions for dB, depending on if we are working with magnitude or power quantities:
$$dB = 10\log_{10}(P/P_o) = 10\log_{10}(p/p_o)^2 = 20\log_{10}(p/p_o)$$

Thank you for your answer :)
